# How to convert the Appium-Python code from Sync to Async

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, python-appium

```
from time import sleep

import Asyncio as Asyncio
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy


desired_caps = {
    "app": "/home/ubuntu/mobile_automation/sample.apk",
    "platformName": "Android",
    "deviceName": "ubuntu",
    "ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError": "true",
    # "appium:udid": "emulator-5554",
    "unicodeKeyboard": True,
    "resetKeyboard": True,
    "autoGrantPermissions": True,
    "adbExecTimeout": 60000,
    "headless":True
}
try:
    # Connect to the appium server and open the app
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # Find and click the necessary elements
    bank_login_button = driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.ID, value='com.indigo.sample:id/btn_register_login')
    bank_login_button.click()
    print("Webdriver Connected")
```

How to convert this appium python webdiver connection sync to async in python ?
is there any way to convert this?

I need an conversion of sync to async for appium webdriver in python.
Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: I dont have any idea about sync to async thats why i'm asking like this from the internet i cant find any resources that related to appium-python Async